# How to get LIon's window resize NSCursor?

Tags: cocoa, resize, osx-lion, nscursor

The `NSCursor` documentation lists a number of resize cursors, but they are all of the variety used to resize panes inside of a window: [NSCursor Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nscursor_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

How do I get the resize cursors which OS X uses for resizing window borders?
(I.e., the arrows *without* the bar in the middle.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Native OSX Lion resize cursor for custom NSWindow or NSView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10733228/native-osx-lion-resize-cursor-for-custom-nswindow-or-nsview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicate of 
[Native OSX Lion resize cursor for custom NSWindow or NSView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10733228/native-osx-lion-resize-cursor-for-custom-nswindow-or-nsview)

See particularly the second answer, with Retina images.